# OpenCart skip "Add to cart", straight to checkout

Tags: php, checkout, opencart

I would like to know if it is possible to skip "Add to cart" step in OpenCart for specific products, and when the user clicks on them, send him straight to the checkout page. But only for specific products.

Thanks,
Iraklis

Answer (score 1):

(This applies to opencart 1.5.2.x and 1.5.3.x)

Edit the files:catalog/view/theme/yourtheme/template/product/product.tpl and make the following modification:

Find the code:

```
if (json['success']) {
window.location='index.php?route=checkout/cart';
}
```

Replace With Below Code:

```
if (json['success']) {
window.location='index.php?route=checkout/checkout';
}
```

GOOD LUCK

Answer (score 0):

I think to do this you would have to add a checkbox to the admin to make a note of the items you would like the step to be skipped. This would then give you a list of the items you need to skip.

When adding to the cart place a query in the Ajax call php script where it is adding to the cart, from here you can get the product ID and check if that is one of the items to skip, if it is you can header redirect to the checkout.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

For opencart 2.0
Add extra button beside Add to cart button i.e., Buy Now 
Or you can add option in admin which product have to be buy now or add to cart button

for category page
\catalog\view\theme\default\template\product\category.tpl
And same for modules

```
<button type="button" onclick="buynow('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');">
     <i class="fa"></i> 
     <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">Buy Now</span>
     </button> 
     <script>function buynow(pid){cart.add_buynow(pid);}</script>
```

for product page
\catalog\view\theme\default\template\product\product.tpl

```
<button type="button" id="button_buy" data-loading-text="<?php echo $text_loading; ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Buy Now</button>


<script>
$("#button_buy").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
    type: 'post',
    data: $('#product input[type=\'text\'], #product input[type=\'hidden\'], #product input[type=\'radio\']:checked, #product input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, #product select, #product textarea'),
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function() {
      $('#button-buy').button('loading');
    },    
    complete: function() {
      $('#loading-image').html('');
    },
    success: function(json) {

      $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');

      if (json['error']) {
        if (json['error']['option']) {
          for (i in json['error']['option']) {
            var element = $('#input-option' + i.replace('_', '-'));

            if (element.parent().hasClass('input-group')) {
              element.parent().after('<div class="text-danger">' + json['error']['option'][i] + '</div>');
            } else {
              element.after('<div class="text-danger">' + json['error']['option'][i] + '</div>');
            }
          }
        }

        if (json['error']['recurring']) {
          $('select[name=\'recurring_id\']').after('<div class="text-danger">' + json['error']['recurring'] + '</div>');
        }

        // Highlight any found errors
        $('.text-danger').parent().addClass('has-error');
      }

      if (json['success']) {location.href = 'index.php?route=checkout/checkout';  }
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

i am using OpenCart 2.3.0.2.may be this help someone

i added

```
window.location='index.php?route=checkout/checkout';
```

to file opencart/upload/catalog/view/javascript/common.js
line 168.

and it worked like charm.